# MMA 12.2 freezes while closing notebooks with many plots

Tags: performance-tuning, front-end, notebooks, version-12.2

I recently upgraded to 12.2 and revisited some notebooks made last year (presumably in 12.0 or 12.1). It quite often happens for big notebooks (typically larger than or around 200MB) that MMA 12.2 completely freezes while closing that notebook. Usually, those notebooks contain dozens of cells with 2D plottings and codes.

Before closing with `Command + w` on Mac I usually just open and browse and sometimes make amendments and save. (It happens even when I just browse and make no change.) After waiting for like 15 minutes the front end is still freezing and I have no choice but force quit. But I did notice that one 160MB notebook finally closed after being frozen for like 10 minutes and the front end was back to my control in the end... This never happens before if I recall correctly.

Comment: You may have better luck by contacting Wolfram Support

Comment: I have the same problem with MMA12.2 on WINDOWS 10. MMA is frozen. Nothing happens and noa data are recorder on the harddrive. Fortunately, I made a backup before running MMA. But, it is very frustrating, and abnormal.